# Remove cck field from nodes body

Tags: 6, nodes, entities

I have defined a cck field but I don't want it to be printed out in posts body.

I print body in this way:

```
<?php print $node->body; ?>
```

but cck filed still exists. I want to use value of that field for some other purpose.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Display Fields in CCK, eg `www.yourhost.com/admin/content/node-type/NODETYPE/display`, you can exclude fields from the `$content` variable that is passed to the node template.  I'd look into that and use `$content` instead of `$node->body` if it isn't excluded from there as well.

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma, Is this for Drupal 6?

Comment: yep, this works for Drupal 6.